# Set Constraint To Display Date In MMDDYYYY Format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 - and used this syntax to add a Constraint to my table

```
ALTER TABLE ProdData ADD CONSTRAINT Cst_TodaysDate DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR InputOn
```

ProdData is my table name
Cst_TodaysDate is my Constraint Name
GetDate() is the default value
InputOn is the field I want the GetDate() added to

Now the problem I have is that the Constraint when viewed is in this format:
Aug 15 2016  2:20PM

And I want it to be in
2016-08-15 14:20:34.633

Did I set up the constraint incorrect?  What must I alter in order to get the date to display MM/DD/YYYY format?

If I run `Select GetDate()` from within my SSMS I get the proper output of 2016-08-15 14:20:34.633 - so why does a Constraint field show this differently?

Comment: You'll need to use the CONVERT function with the appropriate style to format the date like that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - is there no way I can set the Constraint to be in the same format that a datetime field would be?  And if in SSMS I just run Select GetDate() I get the output I want 2016-08-15 14:20:34.633

Comment: Yeah, you need to use convert around GETDATE() to format it in the constraint.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - Use CONVERT(GetDate())  - I know that is not exactly right, but proof of concept of what I need to do - when creating the Constraint?

Comment: Yep, just check out the different formatting options for the one you want.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - but if I run a Select GetDate() statement in SSMS it displays the correct format.  Why does my constraint not?

Comment: What's the data type of the column that constraint is on?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - Ah i think you found the issue.  The data type is nvarchar(255) - Do I drop the constraint, alter the data type, then re-create the constraint?

Comment: Yeah, that should work. Just be careful if this is a large table, or if people are actively using it.

Comment: Honestly, the app should *present* the data in the proper format. Formatting at the database level wouldn't be the best - unless it's the only thing you can do.

Comment: @SeanGallardy - I am using access 2013 as a front-end and the powers above were complaining about the formatting (and I had exhausted all options of formatting at the database level)

Comment: So, is your actual question is: "How to present date in the format of #2016-08-15 14:20:34.633# in MS Access?" ???

Comment: @SeanGallardy what's the overhead of using convert on a date here? Would agree for string formatting (proper case etc.).

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Given the app is Access... little to none. The textbox or report label should have a format mask, though, which can be edited. It's more about having data stay in one structure and letting applications decide how it should be chosen. Why not keep financial numbers as nvarchars? It'd make it super easy to put into text fields in the app... ;)